# goto unexpected at this time error for game test

Tags: batch-file, goto

When I run this, it keeps saying "goto" unexpected at this time. I have tried to solve the issue, but it won't work.

Here is the code:

```
@echo off
color 0a
title TEST FOR HACK SIM
:menu
ECHO         what do you want to test?
echo.
echo   -open disk
echo   -save save
echo   -open save
echo.
echo.
set /p choice= choose one:
if %choice% == "open disk" goto disk
if %choice% == "open save" goto saveo
if %choice% == "save save" goto saves
:disk
call D:\
echo did it work!?
goto menu

:saveo
cls
pause
(
set /p save=
)<C:\Users\%username%\Searches\savefiles.txt
echo %save%
pause
goto menu

:saves
set /p fun= what number do you want?>
(
echo %fun%
)>C:\Users\%username%\Searches\savefiles.txt
```

Comment: Batch includes quotes as part of the string it's comparing. `%choice%` should be `"%choice%"`.

Comment: What do you expect `call D:\\` to do?

Comment: You could add switch `/I` to your `if` statements like `if /I "%choice%"==open disk"` to make the comparison case-insensitively. As an alternative to `set /P` and `if`, you might be interested in the `choice` command -- open a command prompt window, type `choice /?` and read the help to find out how it works...

Comment: You should identify the line which produces the error. This can be done with `ECHO ON` at the beginning or with additional `ECHO #1`, `ECHO #2` until you know which line causes the problem.